# mobile not allowing scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, mobile-website

It is my first site and I am not able to scroll anywhere on the page from my android phone.  I'm probably missing something simple!
Here is a part from my  css for the site:

```
  html,body {
        min-width: 320px;
}
body, input, select, textarea {
        font-size: 11pt;  
        padding: 3px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        }   
#bg {
        background-size: contain;
        width: 1500px;
    }
 div {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: scroll;
} 
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:15px !important;
} 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px !important;
    border-radius:5px !important ;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
} 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px !important;
    border-radius:5px !important;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
} 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
} 
div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the viewport in you meta tags? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow` style property to your body tag.

```
html,body {
      min-width: 320px;
      overflow-y: scroll;}
```